# Javascript Drop Down Menu not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

I am trying to make a drop down menu with Javascript (no JQuery). In my HTML, I have an unordered list that contains two list items, each containing an anchor and an unordered list with more list items inside.

I am not concerned about the menus looking pretty, just that the Javascript works. Right now, I am trying to get it to set up event listeners through a 
while loop so that when the top level list items are moused over, the class of the lower list itemsnwill change from one in which the CSS is set to display:none; to a class that has display:block; to make them appear.

I only have two tabs here, but that is because I shortened it from a list of ten tabs. I also don't care about any further submenus.

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xL5pukd5/

HTML:

```
<header>
  <!-- <ul>   <li><a></a><ul>   <li><a></a></li>   -->
  <!-- dd-menu dd-menu-tab dd-menu-tab-anchor dd-submenu dd-submenu-tab dd-submenu-tab-anchor -->
  <nav id="dd-menu-container">
    <ul id="dd-menu">
      <li class="dd-menu-tab">
        <a href="link1.htm" class="dd-menu-tab-anchor" title="Link1">Link 1</a>
        <ul class="dd-submenu">
          <li class="dd-submenu-tab">
            <a href="#" class="dd-submenu-tab-anchor">SubLink1a</a></li>
          <li class="dd-submenu-tab">
            <a href="#" class="dd-submenu-tab-anchor">Sublink1b</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="dd-menu-tab">
        <a href="link2.htm" class="dd-menu-tab-anchor" title="link2">Link2</a>
        <ul class="dd-submenu">
          <li class="dd-submenu-tab">
            <a href="#" class="dd-submenu-tab-anchor">Sublimn2a</a></li>
          <li class="dd-submenu-tab">
            <a href="#" class="dd-submenu-tab-anchor">Sublink2b</a></li>
          <li class="dd-submenu-tab">
            <a href="#" class="dd-submenu-tab-anchor">Sublink2c</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

  </nav>

</header>
```

JavaScript:

```
getTabs = function(elementClass) {
  var tabs = document.getElementsByClassName(elementClass);
  return tabs
};
getSubmenus = function(elementClass) {
  var submenus = document.getElemenetsByClassName(elementClass);
  return submenus;
};

window.onload = function {
  var tabs = getTabs("dd-menu-tab");
  var submenus = getSubmenus("dd-submenu");
  var tabNumber = tabs.length - 1;
  var currentTab = 0;
  while (currentTab <= tabNumber) {
    tabs[currentTab].onmouseover = function {
      submenus[currentTab].className = "dd-submenu-onmouseover"
    };
    tabs[currentTab].onmouseout = function {
      submenus[curenetTab].className = "dd-submenu"
    };
    currentTab += 1;
  }
};
```

CSS:

```
.dd-submenu {
  display: none;
}

.dd-submenu-onmouseover {
  display: block;
}
```

I've tried using other prewritten drop down menu methods, but I couldn't get them to work, so I tried to create my own. Thanks in advance to any help :)

Comment: You forgot to add _()_ brackets in window.onload three times with function .

Comment: Oh, thats right. If i'm not passing any parameters, does that make a difference on whether the function runs or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your script, including typos are said in the comment and [wrong use of a closure variable in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example).

But you really don't need js to fix this, you can use the `:hover` css selector to do it like

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav {
  display: block;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: beige;
}
.dd-menu-tab-anchor {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
}
.dd-menu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.dd-menu-tab {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: auto;
  padding-right: auto;
  width: 9%;
  text-align: center;
}
.dd-submenu {
  display: none;
}
.dd-menu-tab:hover .dd-submenu {
  display: block;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #3300FF;
  border: 2px;
  border-color: white;
}
a {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <!-- <ul>   <li><a></a><ul>   <li><a></a></li>   -->
  <!-- dd-menu dd-menu-tab dd-menu-tab-anchor dd-submenu dd-submenu-tab dd-submenu-tab-anchor -->
  <nav id="dd-menu-container">
    <ul id="dd-menu">
      <li id="dd-menu-tab1" class="dd-menu-tab">
        <a href="link1.htm" class="dd-menu-tab-anchor" title="Link1">Link 1</a>
        <ul id="dd-submenu1" class="dd-submenu">
          <li id="dd-submenu1-tab1" class="dd-submenu-tab">
            <a href="link2" id="dd-menu-tab-anchor" class="">SubLink1a</a>
          </li>
          <li id="dd-submenu1-tab2" class="dd-submenu-tab">
            <a href="" id="" class="">Sublink1b</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="dd-menu-tab2" class="dd-menu-tab">
        <a href="link2.htm" id="link2" class="dd-menu-tab-anchor" title="link2">Link2</a>
        <ul id="dd-submenu2" class="dd-submenu">
          <li id="dd-submenu2-tab1" class="dd-submenu-tab">
            <a href="#" id="#" class="dd-submenu-tab-anchor">Sublimn2a</a>
          </li>
          <li id="dd-submenu2-tab2" class="dd-submenu-tab">
            <a href="#" id="#" class="dd-submenu-tab-anchor">Sublink2b</a>
          </li>
          <li id="dd-submenu2-tab3" class="dd-submenu-tab">
            <a href="#" id="#" class="dd-submenu-tab-anchor">Sublink2c</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>

  </nav>

</header>
<div>
  <h1 id="site title">Website.com</h1>
</div>

<body>
  <p>First paragraph sample text</p>
  <p>Second paragraph sample text</p>
  <p>Third paragraph sample text</p>


</body>
<footer>
  <p>
    References
  </p>
  <!-- <script src="file.js" type="text/javascript"></script> -->
</footer>

</html>
```

---

If you still want to continue using your logic

```js
getTabs = function(elementClass) {
  var tabs = document.getElementsByClassName(elementClass);
  console.log(tabs);
  return tabs
};
getSubmenus = function(elementClass) {
  var submenus = document.getElementsByClassName(elementClass);
  console.log(submenus);
  return submenus;
};

window.onload = function() {
  var tabs = getTabs("dd-menu-tab");
  var submenus = getSubmenus("dd-submenu");
  var tabNumber = tabs.length - 1;
  var currentTab = 0;
  [].forEach.call(tabs, function(el, idx) {
    var submenu = submenus[idx];
    el.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
      submenu.className = "dd-submenu-onmouseover"
    });
    el.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
      submenu.className = "dd-submenu"
    });
  })
};
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav {
  display: block;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: beige;
}
.dd-menu-tab-anchor {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
}
.dd-menu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.dd-menu-tab {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: auto;
  padding-right: auto;
  width: 9%;
  text-align: center;
}
.dd-submenu {
  display: none;
}
.dd-submenu-onmouseover {
  display: block;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #3300FF;
  border: 2px;
  border-color: white;
}
a {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <!-- <ul>   <li><a></a><ul>   <li><a></a></li>   -->
  <!-- dd-menu dd-menu-tab dd-menu-tab-anchor dd-submenu dd-submenu-tab dd-submenu-tab-anchor -->
  <nav id="dd-menu-container">
    <ul id="dd-menu">
      <li id="dd-menu-tab1" class="dd-menu-tab">
        <a href="link1.htm" class="dd-menu-tab-anchor" title="Link1">Link 1</a>
        <ul id="dd-submenu1" class="dd-submenu">
          <li id="dd-submenu1-tab1" class="dd-submenu-tab">
            <a href="link2" id="dd-menu-tab-anchor" class="">SubLink1a</a>
          </li>
          <li id="dd-submenu1-tab2" class="dd-submenu-tab">
            <a href="" id="" class="">Sublink1b</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="dd-menu-tab2" class="dd-menu-tab">
        <a href="link2.htm" id="link2" class="dd-menu-tab-anchor" title="link2">Link2</a>
        <ul id="dd-submenu2" class="dd-submenu">
          <li id="dd-submenu2-tab1" class="dd-submenu-tab">
            <a href="#" id="#" class="dd-submenu-tab-anchor">Sublimn2a</a>
          </li>
          <li id="dd-submenu2-tab2" class="dd-submenu-tab">
            <a href="#" id="#" class="dd-submenu-tab-anchor">Sublink2b</a>
          </li>
          <li id="dd-submenu2-tab3" class="dd-submenu-tab">
            <a href="#" id="#" class="dd-submenu-tab-anchor">Sublink2c</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>

  </nav>

</header>
<div>
  <h1 id="site title">Website.com</h1>
</div>

<body>
  <p>First paragraph sample text</p>
  <p>Second paragraph sample text</p>
  <p>Third paragraph sample text</p>


</body>
<footer>
  <p>
    References
  </p>
</footer>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/akr1vjLb/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It really helped. I'm wondering why the CSS bit that says: dd-menu-tab:hover dd-submenu {display: block} allows the the submenu to stay up even after the mouse pointer has left the tab?

Comment: Also, im confused about the javascript that says [].forEach.call - for the function that is being used, is tabs passing to the function in the place of the function's "el" parameter?

Answer (score 0):

```js
getTabs = function(elementClass) {
  var tabs = document.getElementsByClassName(elementClass);
  console.log(tabs);
  return tabs
};
getSubmenus = function(elementClass) {
  var submenus = document.getElemenetsByClassName(elementClass);
  console.log(submenus);
  return submenus;
};

window.onload = function {
  var tabs = getTabs("dd-menu-tab");
  var submenus = getSubmenus("dd-submenu");
  var tabNumber = tabs.length - 1;
  var currentTab = 0;
  while (currentTab <= tabNumber) {
    tabs[currentTab].onmouseover = function {
      submenus[currentTab].className = "dd-submenu-onmouseover"
    };
    tabs[currentTab].onmouseout = function {
      submenus[curenetTab].className = "dd-submenu"
    };
    currentTab += 1;
  }
};
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav {
  display: block;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: beige;
}
.dd-menu-tab-anchor {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
}
.dd-menu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.dd-menu-tab {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: auto;
  padding-right: auto;
  width: 9%;
  text-align: center;
}
.dd-submenu {
  display: none;
}
.dd-menu-tab:hover .dd-submenu {
  position:absolute;
  display: block;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #3300FF;
  border: 2px;
  border-color: white;
}
a {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <!-- <ul>   <li><a></a><ul>   <li><a></a></li>   -->
  <!-- dd-menu dd-menu-tab dd-menu-tab-anchor dd-submenu dd-submenu-tab dd-submenu-tab-anchor -->
  <nav id="dd-menu-container">
    <ul id="dd-menu">
      <li id="dd-menu-tab1" class="dd-menu-tab">
        <a href="link1.htm" class="dd-menu-tab-anchor" title="Link1">Link 1</a>
        <ul id="dd-submenu1" class="dd-submenu">
          <li id="dd-submenu1-tab1" class="dd-submenu-tab">
            <a href="link2" id="dd-menu-tab-anchor" class="">SubLink1a</a></li>
          <li id="dd-submenu1-tab2" class="dd-submenu-tab">
            <a href="" id="" class="">Sublink1b</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="dd-menu-tab2" class="dd-menu-tab">
        <a href="link2.htm" id="link2" class="dd-menu-tab-anchor" title="link2">Link2</a>
        <ul id="dd-submenu2" class="dd-submenu">
          <li id="dd-submenu2-tab1" class="dd-submenu-tab">
            <a href="#" id="#" class="dd-submenu-tab-anchor">Sublimn2a</a></li>
          <li id="dd-submenu2-tab2" class="dd-submenu-tab">
            <a href="#" id="#" class="dd-submenu-tab-anchor">Sublink2b</a></li>
          <li id="dd-submenu2-tab3" class="dd-submenu-tab">
            <a href="#" id="#" class="dd-submenu-tab-anchor">Sublink2c</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

  </nav>

</header>
<div>
  <h1 id="site title">Website.com</h1>
</div>

<body>
  <p>First paragraph sample text</p>
  <p>Second paragraph sample text</p>
  <p>Third paragraph sample text</p>


</body>
<footer>
  <p>
    References
  </p>
  <!-- <script src="file.js" type="text/javascript"></script> -->
</footer>

</html>
```